# How to keep my alarm to be ringing for 1 minute in android?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I need to ring my alarm for 1 minute on my application.But it just ringing only for a single second.

Suggestions plz..
Thanks for your precious time!..

Please find my sources for reference

**AndroidAlarmService.java**

```
public class AndroidAlarmService extends Activity {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private static final int PERIOD=60000; // 1 minute

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

 AlarmManager aM = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

 Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);
 c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AndroidAlarmService.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


 aM.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),PERIOD,pendingIntent);

    }
 }
```

**RepeatingAlarm.java**

```
 public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Started.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        r.play();

        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(500);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think with Ringtone You will have no success. There is a little post on looping ringtones here:

http://xanderx.com/2010/08/25/making-ringtones-loop-on-android/

but I have not tested it. Instead, You can use MediaPlayer for looping and create a custom countdown timer that stops the mediaPlayer onFinished(). But this is only one possible solution....

```
        try {

     Uri ringtoneAlert =  RingtoneManager.
        getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

         mRingtoneLooper = new MediaPlayer();
         mRingtoneLooper.setDataSource(this, ringtoneAlert);

     final AudioManager audioRingtoneManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

     if (audioRingtoneManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {

            mRingtoneLooper.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mRingtoneLooper.setLooping(true);
            mRingtoneLooper.prepare();
            mRingtoneLooper.start();

            //start custom countdown timer for 60 seconds, counts every second down
            //counting every second down is not necessary, You could even set every 5 seconds or whatever You want

            RingtoneStopper stopper = new RingToneStopper(60000,1000);
            stopper.start();
       }
     } catch(Exception e) {

      //do some message to user if some error occurs
   } 

     //define a countdown timer for 60 seconds that stops the MediaPlayer


        public class RingtoneStopper extends CountDownTimer{

             public RingtoneStopper(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                  super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
              }

                   @Override
                     public void onFinish() {
                        mRingtoneLooper.stop();
                 }

                   @Override
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                  //need nothing to do on tick events
                 }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code i think this will helps you.

```
Ringtone _ringtone =  RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
Timer _start_ringtone = new Timer();
    while (_ringtone!=null) {
if(!_ringtone.isPlaying()){
        _ringtone.play();
}
    }
    _start_ringtone.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            _ringtone.stop();
_ringtone=null;
        }
    }, 60000);
```